# How to copy attribute of svg graphic (from html to excel)

Tags: html, excel, vba, svg, explorer

I have created a macro that finds people from the website online base (using their pin numbers) and I want to copy some information about them to excel (like their name, status etc.). 
The search reasult is a table that contains text and objects (svg) and I have the problem with copying objects to excel.
The search result looks like that:

```
<td data-label="Full name">Name</td>
<td data-label="Status" class="results-status">
    <svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="/static/img/sprite.svg#status-caution"></use></svg>
</td>
<td data-label="Location">UK</td>
<td data-label="Details"></td>
```

So I wrote this:

```
Set elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("td")
            Cells(i, 1).Value = elements(0).innerText
            Cells(i, 3).Value = elements(1).innerText
            Cells(i, 4).Value = elements(2).innerText
            Cells(i, 5).Value = elements(3).innerText
```

And unfortunately I don't get anything from elements(1). I guess it doesn't work because this is an object not a text.

I have to get status information from the 2nd row (/static/img/sprite.svg#**status-caution**) and I don't have any idea how to do this. I also tried`img = elements(1).getAttribute()` but msgbox(img) showed only this: [native code]

Comment: may be try innerhtml and then string parsing.

Comment: innerhtml gives me svg code, not <use.....> part. this is what I got using innerhtml: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path fill="#ff8900" d="M 20 0 C 8.953 0 0 8.955 0  -5.683 -5.18 Z" /><circle fill="#ff8900" cx="20" cy="28.801" r="1.6" /></svg> which would be usefull if I only could paste this graphic into excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this:**

```
Cells(i, 3).Value = elements(1).Children(0).Children(0).getAttribute("xlink:href")
```

Explain:

1. Because elements are set as `doc.getElementsByTagName("td")` and the tagname "use" is under two level, add `Children(0).Children(0).` or `firstElementChild.firstElementChild` to get `href`.
2. `elements(1).Children(0).Children(0).href` gets nothing, instead, take `.getAttribute("xlink:href")` to replace `.href`.

Or another solution would be:

```
Set elements = doc.getElementsByClassName("results-status")

Cells(i, 3).Value = elements(0).firstElementChild.firstElementChild.getAttribute("xlink:href")
```

[Attached screenshot of working code and tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soA0b.png)

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: Add a bit explanation in your answer else it will be closed.